# “Prepare failed.: status=0x1” Exception occurred when streaming

Tags: android, streaming

I am using StreamProxy class in order to stream with using `MediaPlayer`. So, i wrote some codes as follow to start local server :

```
ProxyStream proxyStream = new ProxyStream();
proxyStream.init();
proxyStream.start();
```

So, the local server is created successfully and the special port has obtained. (`port 41257` obtained). I know that we can access web files with try the link as `http://127.0.0.1:41257/http://printf.ir/music/01.mp3`. Now, i want to stream with using MediaPlayer object and try the code as follow :

```
this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource("127.0.0.1:41257/http://printf.ir/music/01.wma");
this.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
this.mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

On run time, the exception occurred in third line of code, and i pasted it here :

```
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at com.exmaple.stream.StreamMediaPlayerActivity.onClick(StreamMediaPlayerActivity.java:83)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-17 18:49:49.989: W/System.err(10444): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i stream with using MediaPlayer ?! Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in your advance :)

Comment: This is definitely a malformed URL:`http://127.0.0.1:41257/http://printf.ir/music/01.wma`, Try using this one:`http://127.0.0.1:41257/` and see what happen.

Comment: But i want to stream `http://printf.ir/music/01.wma`, and how can i stream it with using `http://127.0.0.1:41257`?!

Comment: What does StreamProxy actually do is download media contents from  `http://printf.ir/music/01.wma` and re-publish it to `http://127.0.0.1:41257/`.

Comment: I know it, but where i insert my link to re-publish it in `http://127.0.0.1:41257/` ?

Comment: I have read the code again, what you did original is correct, try this: `this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://127.0.0.1:41257/http://printf.ir/music/01.mp3")‌​;`

Comment: I have tried it just now, but the above exception occurred again.

Comment: Did you try direct connection in the same context?
What was the outcome?

Comment: Yes, i've tried direct connection, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
mediaPlayer.start();
statusText.setText("Playing...");
}
});
}
```

[Here](http://www.newyyz.com/ntgsite/2012/05/android-using-the-mediaplayer-for-online-streams/) is a tutorial that goes through the whole process of Using the MediaPlayer for Online Streams, it is the second part of the tutorial... I used this tutorial about 3 months ago for one of my projects so it does work, you should give it ago

Comment: are you getting the same thing when you try this one or is it a different error?

Comment: and what happens if you just enter http://printf.ir/music/01.wma and not http://127.0.0.1:41257/http://printf.ir/music/01.mp3?

Comment: When i use the `printf.ir/music/01.wma`, because of network authentication, i faced the 407, Authentication Error! So, i need to download from remote server and stream from LOCAL Socket.